# Keycloak, How to secure spring boot back end that doesn't serve web pages?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, authorization, keycloak

I have a front end that I secured with keycloak by having our login page make a POST request to the Keycloak server, so I can get the access token (JWT). We do not use the kecloak provided login page. This front end makes REST calls to the back end (spring-boot) servlet that uses those calls to query the database and send data back to the front end. Most tutorials I see about securing a spring-boot app use spring-boot to serve webpages, and use the default keycloak login page. My question is, How can I use the keycloak spring-boot adapter without having used the keycloak login page? Is there some way I can pass the keycloak access token in each request, equivalent to how keycloak might expect?

I am using keycloak version 7.0.0 and am securing each endpoint by role.

I have followed this tutorial to the extent that I can,
except my @Controller is used differently and does not use any spring-boot Model objects to serve web pages as mentioned before. Currently every request returns a 500 error. So that brought me to this question.
https://www.thomasvitale.com/spring-boot-keycloak-security/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad and cant fit in Stackoverflow but at last Stackoverflow's platform to help each and other so here is one solution.

In your rest api project create a Keycloak functionality class ,which will authenticate all the request coming to fetch data.

Lets have a look one case ,suppose i want create a Role in Keycloak as well in my DB what i have to do ?

Suppose Request will come from Rest client or GUI -> Request should contain the Token so each request have a valid token so your code for creating Role in Keycloak DB will be something like this

```
public void createRole(String createRoleAPIurl,String accessToken){
RoleRepresentation roleRepresentation = new RoleRepresentation();
roleRepresentation.setName(role.getRoleName());
roleRepresentation.setDescription(role.getDescription());
String convertValue = mapper.writeValueAsString(roleRepresentation);
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(convertValue);
response = keycloakUtil.fetchURLResponse(createRoleAPIurl, accessToken, entity);
}
```

and

```
public CloseableHttpResponse fetchURLResponse(String createRoleAPIurl, String accessToken, StringEntity entity)
            throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);
            postRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + accessToken);
            postRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            postRequest.setEntity(entity);
            response = httpclient.execute(postRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return response;
    }
```

In this example query is going to Keycloak so url would be like `https://<PORT>:<IP>/auth/roles` this url just for example in your case you have to write another method which will validate the token if token will be validated then only you will allow the request to fetch data from your DB otherwise you can throw some exception or pass message. So your each request should come with a valid Token and now its duty to validate the token and then only allow to access your resources.

Hope it will help you.